# [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281eb7360

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase

Does anybody know what this error means? I'm developing in Flutter and everything worked fine but now when I'm trying to reach Firebase Auth this happens and the app crashes...

Thats the Error Message:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281eb7360
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281eb7360'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c1d32a48 0x1c1a59fa4 0x1c1c365a8 0x1c1d36af4 0x1c1d38a7c 0x103221c84 0x1c19ff184 0x1c19a69a4 0x103221bd4 0x1032235c4 0x103222408 0x103088bb8 0x10308bad0 0x103089cd0 0x103087ecc 0x1030794fc 0x10307aa10 0x103079750 0x103078f58 0x1c19fe610 0x1c19ff184 0x1c19ab404 0x1c19abdf8 0x1c19b5314 0x1c1a4eb88 0x1c1a51760)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
* thread #9, queue = 'com.google.firebase.auth.globalWorkQueue', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001c1b29ec4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x1c1b29ec4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1c1b29ee0               ; <+36>
    0x1c1b29ec8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1c1b29ecc <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1c1b29ed0 <+20>: bl     0x1c1b08f64               ; cerror_nocancel
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```

Thats my info.plst maybe its something inside of it
............_______________________________________________________

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>your usage description here</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>your usage description here</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <string>for the video player to run</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>to enhance the user experience looking for an event location</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Wishing Table App</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>wishing_table_app</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
        </dict>
        <dict/>
    </array>
    <!--Facebook Dev Info-->
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
        <string>fb714675723306138</string>
        <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.{key}</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </array>
    <!-- <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>{key}</string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string>{key}</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Wishing Table</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbapi20160328</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array> -->

    <!--End-->
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MBXAAccessToken</key>
    <string>{key}</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To take user profile image</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Shows your location on the map and helps improve the map</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Used to capture audio</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To choose user profile image</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thats the file that throws the error (GTMSessionFetcher)

```
#if !GTM_ALLOW_INSECURE_REQUESTS
+ (BOOL)appAllowsInsecureRequests {
  // If the main bundle Info.plist key NSAppTransportSecurity is present, and it specifies
  // NSAllowsArbitraryLoads, then we need to explicitly enforce secure schemes.
#if GTM_TARGET_SUPPORTS_APP_TRANSPORT_SECURITY
  static BOOL allowsInsecureRequests;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSDictionary *appTransportSecurity =
        [mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSAppTransportSecurity"];
    allowsInsecureRequests =
        [[appTransportSecurity objectForKey:@"NSAllowsArbitraryLoads"] boolValue]; <<< HERE does it break
  });
  return allowsInsecureRequests;
#else
  // For builds targeting iOS 8 or 10.10 and earlier, we want to require fetcher
  // security checks.
  return YES;
#endif  // GTM_TARGET_SUPPORTS_APP_TRANSPORT_SECURITY
}
#else   // GTM_ALLOW_INSECURE_REQUESTS
+ (BOOL)appAllowsInsecureRequests {
  return YES;
}
#endif  // !GTM_
```

Comment: The stacktrace is obfuscated, it's hard to tell what's wrong, but I guess seeing the error, that in a setting, you provided a String instead of a Dictionary... Maybe a wrong plist?

Comment: I added my info.plst maybe you could tell where it might be :/

Comment: I checked your plist, it looks fine! Can you add the code where error happens?

Comment: What changed between it working and not working?

Comment: The error means that something is trying to call an `objectForKey` method  on an instance of `_NSCFString`  which doesn’t support that.  Probably you’re getting a string response rather than a dictionary in Firebase Auth.  It would be helpful to see the code where the error occurs.  Try setting an Obj-C Error breakpoint in Xcode and see what’s in the call stack when it’s triggered.

Comment: Thats my problem...I have done lots of coding and have no clue at what time it might happened. Its only on ios and when communicating with firebase in any form (except for log out)
I haven't touched any of the authentication code

Comment: I think I wasn’t clear.  I’m not referring to setting a break point on a specific line of code.  In the Xcode debugger you can tell to break any time an exception is thrown, but Swift exceptions and Obj-C exceptions are handled differently so they can be enabled separately.

Comment: In the `Debug` menu, select `Breakpoints` and then `Create Exception Breakpoint...`, and of course, make sure you're using a debug build so you can inspect symbols when the breakpoint is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip. I've added the code to my question. I marked the point where it says:  -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x280adc5d0